# Updating custom user attributes with existing Devise users/edit functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My users have a `name` alongside regular Devise columns like email, password, etc. I would like users to be able to edit their own account settings—including their name—at `/users/edit`, which Devise thankfully provides for us out of the box as part of `registrations`.

I added a `name` input to the view (simplified here):

```
= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f|
  = f.input :name, required: false
  = f.input :email, required: true
  = f.input :password, autocomplete: 'off', required: false
  = f.input :password_confirmation, required: false
  = f.submit 'Save'
```

This renders the name correctly in the form, and I can edit and save, however the name is not updated while other things are. I imagined that Devise would simply take whatever `params` are in the form and update the `resource` with those params regardless of what they were, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

I have got it working by overriding the controller (again only most important code shown):

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def update
    resource.name = params[:user][:name]
    resource.save
    super
  end
end
```

This works okay, but is there a simpler, built-in way to do this I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a simpler way. Make a new initializer, preferably `config/initializers/devise.rb`, and write the permitted parameters in that. A basic configuration looks like the following:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
module DevisePermittedParameters

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name])
  end

end

DeviseController.send :include, DevisePermittedParameters
```

It allows module-wise configuration of permitting custom parameters. You can find more details about it [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters).

Comment: Cheers. I ended up adding it to the `application_controller` rather than to the initialiser.

Comment: Adding it to `application_controller` will do the trick, but on the same time, it makes your controller clumsy. Adding that to separate initializer makes it easy to read/configure, and keeps your controller code clean. Anyway, final call is yours :)

Comment: Wouldn't this makes ALL devise controllers having those new fields in the permitted params?

Comment: This might be a preferable approach but I do not think this is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

if you are Looking for simple and easy then try it,
In Application controller add following code snippet which will add your `name` attribute in strong parameter list

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
    protected

        def configure_permitted_parameters
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name
        end
```

hope it will help you.